# JQGrid Datefmt not behaving as expected

Tags: jqgrid

As part of my colModel in a JQGrid, I have the following:

```
{name:'revisedDate', width:220, editable: true, datefmt:'yyyy/mm/dd',edittype:'text',editrules:{date:true, required:true},search:true, stype:'text'}
```

The datefmt and date:true seem to be working as anticipated, except for one special case.  Currently in an edit box if a user enters "2012/04/", jqgrid accepts this as a valid date value, even though it is missing the day of the month.  All other incorrect variations display an error message in the top of the form, with the text: Please enter valid date value - yyyy-mm-dd.

I have also tried changing the colModel to use `datefmt:'yyyy-mm-dd` without success.

Is there anything I'm doing wrong?  My next step would be to roll a custom formatter, but that seems like it should be unnecessary.

Version of JQGrid: 4.3.1

Solution:  I ended up testing a regex against the string in the beforeSubmit event, as well as leaving the `editrules{date:true}` in place.  The bulk of the date validation is done by the built in datefmt, so the below regex really is just a band-aid for that bug.  A more ideal solution would be to do all date validation in the same place, but the usage of this form doesn't merit the extra time that would be put into it.

```
var datePattern = new RegExp(/[0-9]{4}\/[0-9]{2}\/[0-9]{2}/g);
            var revised = $("#revisedDate").val();
            if(!datePattern.test(revised))
            {
                return[false, "Revised Date (YYYY/MM/DD/): Please enter valid date value - YYYY/MM/MM"];
            }
            return [true, "Success"];
```

Comment: My workaround is to just use my own regex and run it in the validator point of the code.  The above seems more like a jqgrid bug than anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can examine the source code of jqGrid which implements `editrules: {date: true}`. It's some lines [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.5/js/grid.common.js#L621-L630) and the internal function `$.jgrid.checkDate` [here](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/v4.4.5/js/grid.common.js#L479-L541). You will see that it has **too many restrictions**. Many formats of the date are not supported. For example the standard "en-us" format of the date (see ['n/j/Y'](https://github.com/tonytomov/jqGrid/blob/master/js/i18n/grid.locale-en.js#L104)) is not supported.

So I would recommend you better to use [custom validation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3acommon_rules#custom_checking_example) instead. I personally never use `editrules: {date: true}`.